# AWS EC2 standard AWS AMI with PHP 7.0 - install libsodium recipe

Tags: php-7, libsodium

(edited for clarity - rolled in accepted answer)

Libsodium has been prepped for PHP 7.  In doing this, the namespace was removed and a prefix of sodium_ for methods and SODIUM_ for constants was added.  Also the version methods were removed.

This github page documents all the new functions and constants and the project provides backward compatibility with the \Sodium namespace: https://github.com/Firehed/sodium/blob/master/src/we_cant_have_nice_things.php

Recipe: install Libsodium on PHP 7 on and AWS AMI

```
# PHP 7.0 Libsodium install AWS AMI
yum install -y php7-pear re2c php70-devel
yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"

pecl7 install libsodium

vi /etc/php-7.0.d/20-libsodium.ini
    ; Enable libsodium extension module
    extension=sodium.so

service httpd restart
```

command line test to verify sodium is installed

```
php7 --info | grep sodium
```

test php function to verify calling pattern for password hash

```
<?php
$password = "hello";
$hash_str = sodium_crypto_pwhash_str(
    $password,
    \SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
    \SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
);
var_dump($password, $hash_str);
```

Thanks to @GracefulRestart for the help.

Comment: Do you see libsodium in your list of modules if you do a `phpinfio()` ??

Comment: only hit for sodium in that is additional ini files parsed: /etc/php-7.0.d/20-libsodium.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple problems here, the first is that your test file appears to be non-functional.

Running your test code with libsodium working in PHP 7 returns the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Sodium\\library_version_major()
```

If you want to check the version, it may be easier to search the data from the phpinfo() function:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
# or from CLI
php7 --info |grep sodium
```

The other problem I notice is in your install steps, you install libsodium both from source and from PECL.  The `make install` command by default places the libraries in /usr/local/lib, while `pecl7 install libsodium` will normally install libraries into the default PHP modules directory.

If you were attempting to install from source, your /etc/php-7.0.d/20-libsodium.ini file is incorrect as that is loading the libsodium libraries you installed from PECL (you can check which directory it is loading from by check the extension_dir ini setting from phpinfo()).

If you only need to install from PECL, you do not need all of the development packages or any manual compiling.

EDIT I modified your posted recipe to remove the extraneous steps of downloading the source and just do everything with PECL:

```
yum install -y php7-pear re2c php70-devel
yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
# PHP 7.0
pecl7 install libsodium
vi /etc/php-7.0.d/20-libsodium.ini
    ; Enable libsodium extension module
    extension=sodium.so
service httpd restart
```

If the YUM repositories for your distribution offer the php7-libsodium package, that would be an even smaller recipe

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks.  i agree that my recipe is a hodgepodge because frankly it hasn't worked either way and i've tried several variations.  i was hoping to find a clear recipe that works that i could reuse.  do you happen to have one handy?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer that has an updated recipe based on your original post.  Remember to use a more valid testing method as the one you originally posted did not seem to run on a system that had php-libsodium in a working state.

Comment: Just to add real quick:  I discovered why your original test was not working.  It appears to come from a book written for an older version of libsodium, the newer version you are installing does not have those functions anymore, hence the error "Call to undefined function Sodium..."  I am pretty sure your original recipe actually got php-libsodium working, you just installed the module twice.

Comment: worked like a champ.  edited the question to explain the solution clearly from the start.  also added a link to conversion github project that shows all the renamed methods and constants.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to this recipe.

```
wget -c https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz 
tar -xvf libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz  
cd libsodium-1.0.18 
./configure
make && make check
make install
sudo pecl7 install -f libsodium
```

pecl7 should install and modify the php.ini file to include the following in the php.ini

```
extension="sodium.so"
```

If you running PHP in Elastic Beanstalk, the following file ./ebextentions/script.config :

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/001_libsodium.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      wget -c https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz && tar -xvf libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz &&  cd libsodium-1.0.18 && ./configure && make && make check && sudo make install && sudo pecl7 install -f libsodium
```